# React Как создать component <details>?

Tags: reactjs

Пробую реализовать элемент [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) для повторного использования в реакт проектах
Подскажите, пожалуйста что я делаю не правильно на примере вот этого элемента из [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-lamarr-nt04r)
Как его улучшить? И как для примера вывeсти значения из testData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там целый ряд проблем

1. Вы создаете компонент с названием `Details` и рендерите в функции `return` этот самый компонент, который создаете. Там должен быть `html` тэг `details` а не компонент
2. Много лишнего и ненужного. Например, `html-parser` вам зачем? Вы можете в `children` просто вставлять JSX, и реакт с ним отлично будет работать. Без всяких строк.
3. `className` также не нуждается в обработке какой-то дополнительной библиотекой. Более того, вы почему то создаете `const classes` и дальше передаете ее во все `html` тэги в компоненте. И получается, что у вас будут навешаны везде одни и те же классы. Что недопустимо в продакшен средах. Обычно `className` передают только на конревой элемент. Тоже самое касается `attrs`. Их также вешать нужно только на корневой элемент
4. По поводу вашего вопроса, мы можете развернуть `testData` при помощи спред оператора при вызове компонента. `<Details {...testData} />` - тогда пропсы передадутся в компонент.
   Результатом всех исправлений станет примерно такой код

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./styles.css";

const Details = ({
  className,
  title,
  children,
  onClick,
  disabled,
  ...attrs
}) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (disabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    } 

    if (onClick) {
      onClick(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <details
      className={className}
      disabled={disabled}
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...attrs}
    >
      <summary>{title}</summary>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </details>
  );
};

Details.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.node,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool
};

Details.defaultProps = {
  className: "",
  title: "Title text",
  children: "Default text",
  onClick: () => {},
  disabled: false
};

const testData = {
  title: "Test text for Title",
  children: (
    <p>
      This is simple text for description about{" "}
      <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details">
        details
      </a>
    </p>
  )
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Details {...testData} />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за развернутый ответ. Я только на начальной стадии познания Реакта.  У меня вопрос, если есть необходимость для summary и div обертки для контента, тоже задавать className их необходимо держать под какими-то другими переменными в отличии от className для details? (Можете показать как будет выглядеть код?)  И ещё, по поводу parser почему то столкнулся с проблемой, что если не распаршивать строку с html тегами, то оно при рендеренги так и отображало эти теги, не знаю с чем это было связано